# Управление псевдоклассами в CSS

Tags: html, css

Пожалуйста, подскажите, что делаю не так:

Задал свойства для введённого тега  и других элементов, оно работает именно так как хочется, но хочу сделать так, чтобы при наведении на любую часть ссылки менялся цвет.

**По факту имею:**

1. при наведении на /num1 меняется цвет всей ссылки;
2. при наведении на любую часть /a кроме вложенного /num1 меняется цвет
   всего текста, кроме обрамлённого

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#div1 a{
    color: #121212;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#div1 a:hover{
    color: #242424;
}

#div1{
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

num1{
    color: crimson;
}

num1:hover{
    color: #242424;
}

#div1 h1{
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 28pt;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css"/>
  <title>Сайт</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="div1">
    <a href="#">
        <h1><num1>>></num1>some_text</h1>
    </a>
</div>
  
 
</body>
</html>
```

Попытка добавить обрамляющий  /  и отдельный id / id:hover никак не поменяла поведение ссылки: **num1:hover** всё так же влияет на **a:hover**, но не наоборот.

Comment: А где вы взяли тег `num1`?

Comment: @doox911 в принципе можно использовать любые теги, попробуйте, или посмотрите как вставляютя яндекс карты - увидите там тег `ymaps`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, в `html5`?

Comment: @doox911  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, тег `num1` всё равно не соответствует стандарту.

Comment: да, я знаю о том, что добавлению тегов предпочтительнее применять обёртки со своими id \ сочетаниями классов )
как я написал ниже в примере, я пытался сделать то же используя только span, но на логику поведения a:hover это не повлияло

Comment: Что-то я не совсем пойму, как должно работать)
Чтобы по наведению на ссылку менялся цвет только вложенного в нее элемента а не всего текста?

Comment: @kost1k сейчас при наведении на текст меняется цвет только текста, при наведении на отдельно подкрашенный элемент - всей ссылки. А пытался сделать так, чтобы при наведении на любую часть ссылки, в т.ч. и "подкрашенного" элемента, менялся цвет всей ссылки

Comment: @DenisGolub Оберни подкрашенный элемент в нормальный тег, например `span` и все будет работать, либо напиши отдельно ховер для элемента находящегося внутри ссылки `#div1 a:hover num1`